# WLST offline jdbc name contains slash

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, offline, slash, wlst

I am trying to create a datasource jdbc for weblogic using WLST offline.

```
cd('/')

create('jdbc/test', 'JDBCSystemResource')

cd('JDBCSystemResource/(jdbc/test)/JdbcResource/(jdbc/test)')
```

but I keep getting an error:

No such element JdbcResource named jdb

On the oracle website they say to use parentheses but still on the JdbcResource part it fails.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you can't use slashes in names when using WLST Offline.  Tucked away in the [WLST Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13715/using_wlst.htm#WLSTG139) ...

```
When using WLST offline, the following characters are not valid in names of
management objects: period (.), forward slash (/), or backward slash (\).
```

I would suggest not having the 'jdbc/' in the name of the data source, you can use it in the JNDI name for the DS since it's this value which a client will use to find it.

UPDATE:

I had interpreted that comment on the use of parentheses as referring to WLST online, but having done a bit more experimenting you are correct and that's not the case.  I used the console to create a data source called 'jdbc/test'.  Then using WLST online I was able to do cd straight to it ...

```
wls:/soa_domain/serverConfig> cd ('JDBCSystemResources/jdbc/test/JDBCResource/jdbc/test')
wls:/soa_domain/serverConfig/JDBCSystemResources/jdbc/test/JDBCResource/jdbc/test> ls()
dr--   InternalProperties
dr--   JDBCConnectionPoolParams
dr--   JDBCDataSourceParams
dr--   JDBCDriverParams
dr--   JDBCOracleParams
dr--   JDBCXAParams
-r--   Name                                     jdbc/test
-r--   Version                                  null
-r-x   isSet                                    Boolean : String(propertyName)
-r-x   unSet                                    Void : String(propertyName)
```

I then tried the same using offline using parentheses around both occurrances of the name and this failed.  I then tried moving up the tree one element at a time and the first three succeeded (so the brackets are definitely for use in offline)...

```
wls:/offline/soa_domain>cd ('JDBCSystemResource/(jdbc/test)/JdbcResource')
wls:/offline/soa_domain/JDBCSystemResource/(jdbc/test)/JdbcResource>ls()
drw-   jdbc/test
```

It's the last element which fails.  Without brackets you get the 'No such element' error ...

```
wls:/offline/soa_domain/JDBCSystemResource/(jdbc/test)/JdbcResource>cd ('jdbc/test')
Error: cd() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
wls:/offline/dev2_soa_domain/JDBCSystemResource/(jdbc/test)/JdbcResource>dumpStack()
com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException:
  com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptException: No such element JdbcResource named jdbc
```

With brackets you get ...

```
wls:/offline/soa_domain/JDBCSystemResource/(jdbc/test)/JdbcResource>cd ('(jdbc/test)')
Error: cd() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
wls:/offline/soa_domain/JDBCSystemResource/(jdbc/test)/JdbcResource>dumpStack()
com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Could not create generic operation:JdbcResource
....
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Could not create generic operation:JdbcResource
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.operation.OperationBuilder.createConfigOperation(OperationBuilder.java:339)
```

So in summary, I think you've found a bug there.  I think your options are either to use WLST online or to not have a slash in the name although it's still fine (and indeed standard practice) have a slash in the JNDI name.

Comment: but right below you can read the following:

_If you need to cd to a management object whose name includes a forward slash (/), surround the object name in parentheses. For example:

cd('JMSQueue/(jms/REGISTRATION_MDB_QUEUE)')_

Comment: the braces around thing worked in navigating a path containing '/' in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation to MBean is need to modified...

Can you try this example script given below?

http://wlstbyexamples.blogspot.in/2010/02/configuring-generic-datasource.html